# Erlang dbg – Debugging on production OTP system with remote shell

Tags: debugging, erlang, erlang-otp

I have an OTP based Erlang application that seems to behave weird.

I want to connect to the erlang shell and trace exactly what is happening.
I can do all my calls to dbg:tracer(), dbg:tp() etc. just fine, however no output is sent to my shell.

I think this might be, because I am connecting via a remote shell.

However, when I call dbg:n(wiwob@vlxd38-wob). I get an error:

```
** exception error: bad argument in an arithmetic expression
     in operator  -/2
        called as wiwob@vlxd38 - wob
```

How can I find out which shell the output is sent to and pipe it to my shell?

Answer (score 3):

The argument to `dbg:n/1` must be an atom and `wiwob@vlxd38-wob` is not an atom, it needs to quoted like `'wiwob@vlxd38-wob'`. For the syntax of an atom, and other data types, see [Atoms](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id67764).

Answer (score 1):

I cannot help you for the dbg problem, you do not give enough information about how you connect the debugger to a process, module ...

For the second point the error is self explanatory, parsing the expression wiwob@vlxd38-wob, the shell try to execute

wiwob@vlxd38 minus wob, which is impossible with 2 atoms.

the function dbg:n/1 has the folowing specs:

```
n(Nodename) -> {ok, Nodename} | {error, Reason}
Nodename = atom()
Reason = term()
```

so you must write your node name as 'wiwob@vlxd38-wob' in order to force the whole expression to be a single atom.